# ¿Palta o aguacate?

Tags: vocabulario, comida, hispanoamérica

En español hay dos maneras de llamar a esta fruta. "Palta" se usa generalmente en América del Sur. Pero,  ¿se sabe cuál es el nombre que se dio en origen a esta fruta para así poder obtener el nombre correcto en español?

Comment: Si me acuerdo bien, en el norte de Sudamerica (eg. Colombia) se dice "aguacate" también.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

¿Por qué tendría que haber un nombre más "correcto" que otro?

El DLE indica que "aguacate" viene del náhuatl "ahuacatl" (y que este también significaba "testículo"). También según el DLE, "palta" es "de or. quechua", esta vez sin dar detalles. Alguna información adicional se encuentra [aquí](http://ucavo.ucr.edu/General/HistoryName.html) (una de las referencias de la Wikipedia en inglés).

Puesto que el aguacate parece haber tenido origen en lo que ahora es México, el nombre que le dieron los aztecas podríamos considerarlo más "original" (aunque yo no diría más "correcto"). De "aguacate" se derivan, a su vez, el francés "avocat" y el inglés "avocado" (entre otros).

Comment: Al parecer la palabra plata proviene del Quechua, asi que no tiene un origen español, quizás correcto no es precisamente el verbo, pero quería abrir el debate, igual me parece una gran respuesta

Comment: @davdomin: Y "aguacate" viene del   náhuatl.

Comment: Que interesante @Charo

Comment: Andaba buscando por qué le dicen "avocado" en inglés, ya que no se parece al original nahuat "ahuacatl". Qué buena referencia pusiste al respecto, que cuenta cómo un gringo que no podía pronunciarlo le empezó a decir "alvacata", y de allí se transformó a "avocado".

Answer (score 3):

En Chile y, creo que en casi toda Argentina, se conoce como **palta**, y según tengo entendido esto es porque los Incas conquistaron los territorios de los indios "Paltas" al sur del actual Ecuador, quienes ya conocían y cultivaban este fruto.

En Chile y Argentina se utilizan muchos vocablos de origen quechua porque los españoles aprendieron esta lengua que era la más extendida en la región y por lo tanto la utilizaron como lengua franca, y así pasaron muchos términos a las tierras ubicadas al sur del actual Perú, centro del Incanato.

Answer (score 1):

Parece ser que el aguacate o palta comenzó a cultivarse primeramente en México . Pero esto no importa a la hora de saber cuan correcto es. Palta y aguacate son igualmente aceptados por la RAE.
Depende del país donde te encuentres hablando te puede parecer más común o menos decir aguacate, pero no es ni más ni menos correcto.

Comment: ¿Tienes alguna referencia que indique que comenzó a cultivarse en Perú? Todo lo que yo he visto (aunque no he sido muy exhaustivo tampoco) sitúa el origen en México.

Comment: Tienes razón, puse Perú en vez de México, y al parecer se cultivó casi 4 o 5000 años antes por estos habitantes. Voy a editar mi respuesta. Gracias por el aviso